# Fourier transform cross product of gradients

Tags: fourier-transform

I got stucked in a simple Fourier transform of a vector calculus equation...

Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be two scalar fields and $\vec{v}$ be a vector fields. Fourier transform the following equation
$$\nabla^2 \vec{v}=\nabla \times (\nabla \lambda \times \nabla \mu)$$

My attempt is:

let $\lambda(x)=\int d\vec{p} \hat{\lambda}_p e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}$ and $\mu(x)=\int d\vec{q} \hat{\mu}_q e^{i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{x}}$
$$\nabla \times \int d\vec{p}\,\, \, (i\vec{p})\hat{\lambda}_p e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} \times \int d\vec{q} \,\,\, (i\vec{q})\hat{\mu}_q e^{i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{x}} $$
$$=\nabla \times \int \int d\vec{p}\,d\vec{q} \,\, (-\vec{p}\times \vec{q}) \hat{\lambda}_p \hat{\mu}_q e^{i(\vec{p}+\vec{q})\cdot\vec{x}}$$
$$-i\int \int d\vec{p}\,d\vec{q} \,\, ((\vec{p}+\vec{q})\times (\vec{p}\times \vec{q})) \hat{\lambda}_p \hat{\mu}_q e^{i(\vec{p}+\vec{q})\cdot\vec{x}} $$
which would vanish since $$(\vec{p}+\vec{q})\times (\vec{p}\times \vec{q})=0$$

Could anyone give a hint on what I did wrong?

Edits:
One condition on $\vec{v}$ is that it is divergence-free, i.e. $\nabla\cdot \vec{v}=0$. This might be important but I forgot to state.

The book claims that
$$v(\vec{k})=\int \int \,d\vec{k}_1 \,d\vec{k}_2\, \varphi(\vec{k}_1,\vec{k}_2) a^*(k_1)\,a(\vec{k}_2) \, \delta(\vec{k}+\vec{k}_1-\vec{k}_2)$$
where
$$\varphi(\vec{k}_1,\vec{k}_2)=\frac{1}{2(2\pi)^{3/2}}[\vec{k}_1+\vec{k}_2-(\vec{k}_1-\vec{k}_2)\frac{k_1^2-k_2^2}{|\vec{k}_1-\vec{k}_2|^2}]$$
and a transition of varialbe is defined as below
$$\hat{\mu}(\vec{k})=\frac{a(\vec{k})+a^*(-\vec{k})}{\sqrt{2}},\quad \hat{\lambda}(\vec{k})=\frac{a(\vec{k})-a^*(-\vec{k})}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: You are doing right. Gradient of a scalar field is directed along a radius-vector, so $[\vec\nabla\lambda\times\vec\nabla\mu]=0$. Formally, if we denote $r=\sqrt{x^2_1+x^2_2+...+x^2_n}$, $\vec\nabla\lambda=\sum_i \vec{e_i}\frac{d}{dx_i}\lambda(r)=\sum_i( \frac{d}{dr}\lambda(r))\vec{e_i}\frac{d}{dx_i}r=(\frac{d}{dr}\lambda(r))\frac{1}{r}\sum_i  x_i\vec{e_i}=f'(r)\frac{\vec r}{r}\sim \vec{r}$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thanks! But the book gives an non-zero expression...

Comment: This is strange... could you give a bit more details?

Comment: @Svyatoslav I am so sorry for my late reply (was on trip and had no access to  internet). I have added the book's claim. Just one observation: it seems you first comment assumed isotropy, i.e. $\lambda$ only depends on scalar $r$ but not vector $\vec{r}$. Thanks again!